# Input various text below different images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to html, css and javascript. It's been wrecking my mind how I should input text below the images. I couldn't find any solution regarding it. Please share your knowledge with me. So what I want is basically if I click onto 'square' button it will appear a square with a text:square below it. If i click onto a 'circle' button it will appear a circle with a text: circle below the image.

This is my code. What should i Add-on to make it work?

```
    <script>
    function square()
    { 
     document.getElementById("square").src = "square.png";
     }

     function circle()
    { 
     document.getElementById("square").src = "circle.png"; 
     } 
   function triangle() 
    { 
     document.getElementById("square").src = "triangle.png";
    } 

  </script>



  <hr>
  <h2>Part 2</h2>
  <hr>
  <button onClick="square()">square</button>
  <button onClick="circle()">circle</button>
  <button onClick="triangle()">triangle</button>
  <br />
  <img id="square" src="square.png">
  <br />
   Square
  <hr>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote Java instead of JavaScript in your question, please be more aware :)

Regarding your question, see my example:
I also use [getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) just like you did. To manipulate the text I used [.innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp). If you would like to test the picture part, just remove the //-s from the beginning of the rows in your local setup: those are [comments](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp).

```js
    function square() { 
      //document.getElementById("shape").src = "square.png";
      document.getElementById("shapeName").innerHTML= "square";
     }

     function circle() { 
      //document.getElementById("shape").src = "circle.png"; 
      document.getElementById("shapeName").innerHTML= "circle";
     } 
   function triangle() { 
      //document.getElementById("shape").src = "triangle.png";
      document.getElementById("shapeName").innerHTML= "triangle";
    }
```

```html
  <hr>
  <h2>Part 2</h2>
  <hr>
  <button onClick="square()">square</button>
  <button onClick="circle()">circle</button>
  <button onClick="triangle()">triangle</button>
  <br />
  <!-- <img id="shape" src="square.png"> -->
  <br />
   <div id="shapeName">Square</div>
  <hr>
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriella! I'm only 3 days into javascript so do excuse me for being clueless. Cheers!